# Can a combinatorial hardware circuit with no inputs solve a crypto problem?

Tags: feedback, reference-materials

I am noob at electronics but in short I am interested in stable states of circuit with
no inputs which represents a boolean formula.

Let \$f\$ be some hash function, say md5. Restrict the size of input
to be equal to the output (128 bits for md5).

Cryptographer told be it is open problem if there is
solution to \$f(x)=x\$ (treated as sequence of bits).

Implement \$f\$ as pure combinatorial circuit (NO CLOCK),
with 128 \$i_k\$ inputs and 128 outputs \$o_k\$.

For all \$j\$, connect \$i_j\$ with \$o_j\$ so the circuit
doesn't have inputs(basically
loop the circuit \$f\$).

Power on.

Measure (possibly with oscilloscope) \$i_j=o_j\$.

If you are lucky to hit stable state (logically consistent), you have solved
\$f(x)=x\$.

In an unstable stable (no solution), maybe one will measure very
high frequency.

Probably this is well studied, though an
engineer couldn't find reference for the general case.

> 1. Are there references for this?
> 2. If it fails why will it fail?
> 3. If a solution exists is it known for how long it
>      will be found?
> 4. If this makes sense, would please someone try it on something
>      simple, though not entirely trivial?

---

Partial experimental results:

It wasn't easy, but me convinced an engineer to test it
on bare metal.

Take \$n\$ inverters (logical negation) and loop them
in a cycle (basically this corresponds to the cycle
graph \$C_n\$).

There are no input and no outputs.

For even \$n\$ the circuit has exactly 2 stable
states.

For odd \$n\$, there is no stable state since
the boolean formula is unsatisfiable.

The engineer worked with NAND gates on a stand.

Experimentally, for \$n=4\$, the engineer reached
stable state.  Depending on which NAND gates he chose,
the stable state differed.

For \$n=3\$ there was no stable state.
The voltage was in the middle between logical 0-1,
possibly with high frequency which his oscilloscope
couldn't measure.

I wouldn't trust a software simulation for this,
might be wrong.

The experiments were too trivial, so it is
possible electric current to solve easy problems
and not solve hard problems.

Someone suggested this is "adiabatic bruteforce", though
still can't find the right search terms.

Comment: This question is the only result that comes up [searching for "adiabatic bruteforce"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22adiabatic+bruteforce%22).

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello google doesn't index everything. In response to essentially the same question, check the thread, ["adiabatic representation of brute force"](https://cpunks.org//pipermail/cypherpunks/2014-October/005600.html)

Comment: You do in fact have inputs, at the very least those *encoded in the design of the system itself*.  It is entirely possible to solve problems by building a custom circuit for each one, but it's rather inefficient compared to loading inputs into an engine generic to a particular *type* of problem.  Most illustratively, consider an FPGA, where one critical input is a configuration file which controls which internal gates or look-up-tables feed which others.  Often FPGA designs have traditional "inputs" - but it's also possible to change their configuration at runtime for each problem.

Comment: What kind of crypto problem are you trying to solve? f(x) = x? f(x) = y with a fixed value of y? ...

Answer (score 1):

The general field of digital logic without a clock is *asynchronous logic*. Research has been done in this area but it hasn't really been commercialised.

Your cryptographic example might fail for two reasons:

- it may find a cycle, possibly a long one, that produces a sequence of values but does not converge on the desired solution. This is a mathematical aspect of the problem rather than an implementation detail.
- If you use regular logic and don't have some system for keeping signal propagation in sync, you won't compute the right thing at all, as some parts of the answer will be ready before others, which in turn will perturb the input. See the "Muller C-element" for a solution to this.

Your engineer should have told you that you were reinventing the "ring oscillator". These are often used in conjunction with phase-locked-loops to produce high frequency digital clocks that are some multiple of an input clock without using a high-frequency crystal.

Comment: Thank you. What about the other questions? Would you please give reference to peer reviewed papers for as close as what I am asking? In defense of the engineer, she told me "Odd # of inverters is essentially the same as X". I didn't care about X and didn't include it in the questions -- these are just experimental results  about the questions.

Comment: Possibly http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-45238-6_12 ?

Comment: Is there a rough estimate for the time of state change? Probably this will depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrongly assuming that such a machine would always loop through all the possible inputs; this isn't the case. You might enter a loop that does not span through the entire input space.

For example, let's try to solve this cryptographical problem:

> Let H(n) be a hash function, defined thus: H(n) = n + 2. This function takes four bits in and returns four bits. Any carry bit (eg. 15 + 2 = 17 = `10001`) is ignored (in our case, H(17) = 1 = `0001`)
> Find x such that H(x) = 3.

You build a circuit representing the behaviour of H(n): it takes four inputs, and four outputs. Its current output is `0000`. Now, you wire the inputs I1, I2, I3, I4 to the outputs O1, O2, O3, O4. What happens?

> Instant 0: the output is `0000` [0].
> Instant 1: the output is `0010` [2].
> Instant 2: the output is `0100` [4].
> Instant 3: the output is `0110` [6].
> Instant 4: the output is `1000` [8].
> Instant 5: the output is `1010` [10].
> Instant 6: the output is `1100` [12].
> Instant 7: the output is `1110` [14].
>
> Instant 8: the output is `0000` [0].
> Instant 9: the output is `0010` [2].
> ...

See where this is going? The circuit will loop through only a few states, and may never reach the solution.

Now, I thought of a trivial example to illustrate this concept, but this also works for real hashing functions like MD5 or SHA1.

---

Let I = {`0x00...01`, `0x00...02`, ... `0xff...ff`} be the list of 256-bit unsigned integers, and let `S(x): I -> I` be the SHA256 hashing function.

Apply `S(x)` to each element in I. You are extremely likely to find collisions: that is, two values that hash to the same value (say `H(0x00...01) = H(0xEE...EE)`). If a collision exists, then the set I is larger than its image with respect to `S`: that is, there are elements in I which don't have a counterimage, meaning they can't be obtained by hashing a 256-bit value.

**TLDR: It might be mathematically impossible to solve a problem using your method.**

Comment: Have you tried this on metal/silicon? Why it's current output is `0000`?

Comment: Huh, **I am not assuming** "such a machine would always loop through all the possible inputs"

Comment: 0000 is just an example. A circuit will have a particular bootup value. Don't get hung up on particular numbers, the point is that the system may get stuck in a loop that doesn't cover the solution space.

Comment: @pjc50 as I wrote, I am not interested in software simulations. Would you please test this specific counterexample on hardware -- probably this won't be hard for an expert.

Comment: Giulio Muscarellom, what does your analysis suggest for 3 inverters in a loop?

Comment: It is possible to say something is mathematically (im)possible without having to test it. This is not a software simulation. It also has nothing to say about 3 inverters in a loop because that's not a hash function.

Comment: @ChichoGosho: pjc is correct, I picked 0000 as a bootup value, but it could be 1111, 1011, or whatever you want. My point still remains valid: the circuit might enter a loop which prevents it from browsing the entire space of solutions.

Comment: @ChichoGosho: you are, because you assume that either the circuit will stabilize on a specific value, or never stabilize, meaning no solution exists. The latter part is where you're wrong: if such a machine is instable, it only means that *the values tested so far are not solutions*, not that *all the possible values are not solutions*.

Comment: @ChichoGosho: my analysis for 3 (ideal) inverters in series suggests that **this particular machine** covers the entire solution space {0x0, 0x1}, and since it does not stabilize, it is correct to infer that "`NOT(NOT(NOT(x))) = x` has no 1-bit-long solutions".

Comment: @pjc50: technically, `NOT(NOT(NOT(x)))` is a hash function, because each image has a fixed width - 1 bit - and each image has only one counterimage.

Comment: Finally, @ChichoGosho: if you don't trust software simulations, try to implement the hash function I suggested in a real circuit (it's all about using a few adders, an electrical engineer shouldn't have too much trouble implementing it). You will find out that even though the equation `H(x) = 3` does have a solution, it can't be found by the machine.

Comment: Ok, I agree that software simulation might enter a loop (and possibly a real circuit so). Though your example H(n)=n+2 is technically irrelevant to the question. I am asking about H(n)=n which mathematically is \$n \equiv n + 2 \pmod{2^4}\$ which clearly doesn't have solution. I am not asking about H(x)=3. Is there a rough estimate for the time of state change on hardware circuit?

Comment: RE assumptions. I don't claim this will work, I am asking: 2. If it fails why will it fail?

Comment: If you're looking for solutions of \$H(n) = n\$ then yes, my example is not relevant, but my point still remains: the machine might not loop through the solution. Want an example? \$H(n)\equiv 2a+3 \mod{5}\$ will loop like 3->4->1->0->3..., and the solution is \$2\$.

Comment: Ok. If I buy ASIC/FPGA kit can I test stuff like this? (don't like FPGA having clock if I understand correctly).

Comment: I'm no expert about FPGAs, but I'm pretty sure you could test this, yeah. If you're really interested, you should post a new question, which would get the visibility you need and attract more knowledgeable people.